# Cannot resolve symbol (CyanogenMod system apps)

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build following [CyanogenMod (can be found here)](https://github.com/CyanogenMod) projects:

1. android_packages_apps_Contacts
2. android_packages_apps_ContactsCommon
3. android_packages_apps_Calendar
4. android_packages_providers_ContactsProvider
5. android_packages_providers_CalendarProvider

I'm using AndroidStudio. Downloaded and imported the projects.
Changing the Android SDK versions with no result.

The errors are as follows:

- Error:(37, 33) java: package com.google.common.collect does not exist
- Error:(23, 25) java: package com.android.vcard does not exist
- Error:(134, 6) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class com.android.contacts.common.util.SearchUtil

How can I build these projects? Do I need some other libriaries? Maybe I need to use CyanogenMod libriaries instead of Android SDK?

Here is the [detailed info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6BxU.png).

Comment: For the com.google.common.collect I've downloaded guava-18.0.jar library. The problem with com.android.vcard is still present.